# How to access AJAX returned data with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I hava data structure like this which is then returned to another file with AJAX:

```
$data = array();
   $data['message'] = "You are searching: $domain!";
   $data['domain:name'] = "domain.tld";
   $data['domain:registrar'] = "Registrar Ltd.";
   $data['domain:creation'] = "2015-26-05";
   $data['domain:expiry'] = "2016-26-05";
   $data['ns'] = "ns1.somedns.tld";
   $data['owner']['name'] = "Owner Name";
   $data['owner']['type'] = "Org";
   echo json_encode($data);
```

That data is then append to html with AJAX like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'carnetEpp.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        success: function (data) {
            dataType: 'json',
            //console.log(data);
            $('#response').html(data);
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
```

Now I want to pass that returned JSON object to PHP variable, so I can easy manipulate date with PHP. How do I do that? Or is best practice to do it with JS? Basically I want to print every key:pair value, so maybe for in is good choice.

And, I am not sure, should, or must I echo data in my script so AJAX can pick it up, or can I just pass data to variable and then fetch it in AJAX?

Comment: Are you doing a `GET` or a `POST`? Please provide the whole AJAX call.

Comment: See edit, POST. Data is returned as JSON to html, but I want to access this data with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code in success.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj.message);
```

OR

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj.message);
```

You will get the message sent from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

before sending data in php, setup header for response:

```
    $data = [
        'key' => 'value',
        'key2' => 'vlue2'
    ];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
```

then if u use jquery, [$.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) it really cool solution for handle input json data.